# Hibernate downloads DTD from Internet, how to makie if offline?

Tags: hibernate

Below mapping couses Hibernate to check the schema online. How to make this work offline?

> < !DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
>   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
>   "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

You can use an DTDEntityResolver.

Here are some starters:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=927396

However it depends how you initialize your hibernate system and
which version of hibernate you are using.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was missing www.* - in url, only then the local entity resolver gets the dtd from jar file. I had to debug it to find error. My url didn't have www prefix and wasnt registered in resolver class and thats why it was downloaded every build.